# How to return a view asynchronously? What?

Tags: swift, swiftui, closures

I have a button like this

```
Button(action: {
  // do something
}, label: {
  Text("The price is \(price)")
})
```

The first problem is that the label part of the button expects a View.

Also, the price is retrieved asynchronously from the app store using something like

```
func priceFor(_ productID: String,
                onConclusion:GetPriceHanler?) {
   
    inapp?.fetchProduct(productIdentifiers: [productID],
                       handler: { (result) in
      switch result {
      case .success(let products):
        let products = products
        
        guard let product = products.first
        else {
          onConclusion?("")
          return
        }
        
        onConclusion?("\(product.price)")
        
      case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        onConclusion?("")
      }
    })
  }
```

So, this function runs a closure when it is done.

I have thought about creating another function that returns a view to call this one... something like

```
@ViewBuilder
func priceViewFor(_ productID: String) -> some View { }
```

I am OK if the function returns the price or empty if invalid, but if I do that, I will end inside a closure and from there I cannot return a view.

Something like

```
@ViewBuilder
func priceViewFor(_ productID: String) -> some View {
  myAppStore.priceFor(productID) { price in
  return Text(price) ?????????????
}
```

How in the name of bits do I do that?

Comment: You can’t, the body is synchronous. You can have a conditional of some kind and show  ProgressView while your value loads and then show your view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to have a `@State` that represents the price whether or not it has been fetched. Check this state in the `label:` view builder, and if it is not fetched, show something else.

A simple design is to use an optional:

```
@State var price: String?
```

```
Button {
  // do something
} label: {
    // check if the price has been fetched
    if let price {
        Text("The price is \(price)")
    } else {
        ProgressView("Loading Price...")
    }
}
.disabled(price == nil) // you might want to disable the button before the price has been fetched
.onAppear {
    // set the state in the completion handler
    myAppStore.priceFor(productID) { price in
        self.price = price
    }
}
```

Seeing how the price-fetching could fail, I would suggest using a `Result` instead:

```
@State var price: Result<String, Error>?
```

```
switch price {
case .none:
    ProgressView("Loading Price...")
case .failure(let error):
    Label("Failed! (\(error))", systemImage: "xmark")
case .success(let price):
    Text("The price is \(price)")
}
```

This would mean you would change `priceFor` so that it passes a `Result<String, Error>` to the `onConclusion` closure.

Also, consider rewriting with the Swift Concurrency APIs. The usage would then look like:

```
.task {
    do {
        price = .success(try await myAppStore.priceFor(productID))
    } catch {
        price = .failure(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW, i was making things complicated. This is easier than I thought! THANKS!